# Using curl command for react native to fetch API

Tags: ios, react-native, curl, fetch-api

I'm trying to use the petfinder API for an app I'm creating and following the API documentation which can be found here : https://www.petfinder.com/developers/v2/docs/#developer-resources.

It gives the command : `curl -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={CLIENT-ID}&client_secret={CLIENT-SECRET}" https://api.petfinder.com/v2/oauth2/token`

I'm trying to translate this for react native and used the following code:

```
getAdopt1 = async() => {
fetch('https://api.petfinder.com/v2/oauth2/token', {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
Accept: 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
body: JSON.stringify({
firstParam: "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={CLIENT-ID}&client_secret={CLIENT-SECRET}"
}),
}).then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
let res = JSON.stringify(responseJson)
console.log("Response: "+res)
return responseJson;
})
.catch((error) => {
console.error(error);
})
}
```

However I get the following error:

> Response: {"type":"https‍://httpstatus.es/400","status":400,"title":"unsupported_grant_type","detail":"The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server.","errors":[{"code":"unsupported_grant_type","title":"Unauthorized","message":"The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server. - Check that all required parameters have been provided","details":"The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server. - Check that all required parameters have been provided","href":"http‍://developer.petfinder.com/v2/errors.html#unsupported_grant_type"}],"hint":"Check that all required parameters have been provided"}

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending a JSON request but what the API expects is a Form-Data request.

Try with something like this:

```js
var form = new FormData();

form.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
form.append('client_id', '{CLIENT-ID}');
form.append('client_secret', '{CLIENT-SECRET}');

fetch('https://api.petfinder.com/v2/oauth2/token', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: form,
}).then(response => {
  console.log(response)
}).catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
})
```

Comment: Thank you i think this may have worked however is there a special way to print the response as i got  this as the response:Response {
  "_bodyBlob": Blob {
    "_data": Object {
      "blobId": "598BFE2F-6337-4510-86A8-6B227B9BC000",
      "name": "token",
      "offset": 0,
      "size": 853,
      "type": "application/json",
    },
  },
  "_bodyInit": Blob {
    "_data": Object {
      "blobId": "598BFE2F-6337-4510-86A8-6B227B9BC000",
      "name": "token",
      "offset": 0,
      "size": 853,
      "type": "application/json",
    },
  },

Comment: instead of the response : {
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "access_token": "..."
}
 that the document states I should get

Comment: Use `response.json()` or `response.text()` depending on the format of the response. Please accept the answer if it is correct.